# Where does the Github OAuth token stored in code-server?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, oauth, code-server

In code-server, for a repo cloned using HTTPS and when performing git operation like `git fetch, git push etc.`  For the first time it prompts to sign-in and takes through an OAuth flow, and ends up in the following purple screen:

But in every consecutive git operations it does not prompt to sign-in again. Hence where does the `OAuth token` is stored in code-server?

And how does this OAuth flow happens?

[image: purple screen]

Answer (score 0):

The authorisation code is just for the authorization server's usage. And it's kept in a cache that the authorization endpoint and token endpoint may access.

Comment: I think Keshi needs to know what happens to the GitHub access token that is received. Basically, the location of the credentials that the code server uses when executing Git operations.